# How to stretch a single image as background in android layout?

Tags: android, image, background

Homescreen this contains only search and i want the backgorund image to be my logo.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="178dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1" >

</SearchView>
```

I need the full size image to be displayed this code displays numerous copies of my logo in a tile format.

Comment: what is the problem with this code.

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` you also can use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. 
For more Information please read [Android Scale Type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .9 patch image, to stretch and make it perfect screenfit without stretched tiles. Create 9 patch image from draw9patch or there are lots of tools online also, just write in google you will get it, and make android:scaleType="fitXY".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be that the image you want to use as stretched background is no 9patch.
The 9patchdrawer is in the Android SDK included (but you can also use any image editor)
Important here are the 1px black lines to tell android what parts are for stretching (left and bottom line) and which parts are for the content to be reserved.

The image is then saved as .9.png (android recognizes this automatically as stretchable image)

Here the link how to draw a 9-patch
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1):

You should remove this;

android:background="@drawable/image"

and add this in RelativeLayout;

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 9-patch image to stretch a single image as background in android layout.Image extension is .9.png. You make this type of image using 9-patchdrawer which is stored in **android-sdk-windows\tools\draw9patch.bat** folder.

I think it should be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove those lines from your code

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

and try you will get a full size image in your screen!!

Comment: No i dint get still same problem persists

Comment: i checked ur code!!i am getting a full size image and in the center search view and edittext!!!better u can edit the logo and place it in the background!!

Comment: otherwise use imageview!!it ll be better!!