# dimension of image background for android actionbar

Tags: android

I want to design an image background for my android app's action bar, but have no idea what dimension I have make so that it fits in different screen resolution. 
Do I need to design the same image background separately for each screen densities?
I want to design it in photoshope is that a good option?

any idea Please !

Comment: create a sample project and get the image types and dimensions. Then design an image like that only and resize it to several types of hdpi and ldpi...etc

Comment: @Riad  Thanks from your quick response 
Can you please tell me, where we can get this info from a project

Comment: look at `drawable` folder...images!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stretch a single image as background in android layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821890/how-to-stretch-a-single-image-as-background-in-android-layout)

Comment: @Populus if you read my question once again you will get it that I have asked about actionbar imagebackground dimension, not an Icon dimension in actionbar

Comment: @Raid, if I specify height 96px for xxhdpi, 64 for xhdpi, 48 for hdpi, 32 for mdpi, 24 for ldpi, then what should be the width for each screen resolution thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a gradient which you can store in the **drawable** folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#00445a"
        android:endColor="#00699a"
        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"

        />

</shape>
```

This will prevent all the trouble of trying to adapt to screen sizes.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, I want to design an image background for action bar,using photoshop, but have no idea what dimension should I use >

Comment: Is your image background just a gradient or an actual image?

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 .png versions of the image, for hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi densities.

Comment: what dimension should be the dimension for each

Comment: I want to create an image for action bar what should be its height and width size